# Most effective way to learn Shulchan Aruch

Tags: halacha, shulchan-aruch

I've seen many Seforim talk about learning Shulchan Aruch and the importance of it. However, it always seems that the seforim are telling you to learn the Shulchan Aruch straight. As someone who's limited on time, although  has enough time to learn Shulchan Aruch with its commentaries and contemporary poskim. What should he focus on? Are there seforim that say so? What do you do? Is it all about ones goal? In essence I'd like to know the source of the Halacha and how it applies L'maseh. Is it "good enough" to learn Magen Avraham and Taz and in other Chalakim Shach and Taz etc?

Comment: I'd do Shach (M"A) Taz and Pischei Tshuva but it's not L'maseh, is it ? I guess it is, but can I say it's l'maseh or does the M"B / A"H etc have to say so?

Comment: If you don't learn the Bet Yosef before there is no way, or perhaps to learn SA with Beur HAgra. Without sources it is impossible to understand and to know the Halacha

Comment: Check the introduction to the work. The intended way to learn Shulchan Aruch is as a monthly review for the Beit Yosef. Anything else is "off label" usage, and caveat emptor.

Comment: So you're saying the best way to learn it is Beis Yosef and then Sh"A? @DoubleAA

Comment: @Kouty so then I'd learn Sh"a with Bear Hageolah, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA but I've been told that the relevant stuff by the Beis Yosef is brought in the Nosei Keilim ...?

Comment: @Moshe I don't know what best means, but that's what its author intended. If you do something else you'll probably still learn a bunch of useful Torah, but you may not always get the author's intended results/rulings, for better or worse.

Comment: Beer hagola is not enough

Comment: @DoubleAA Look, I'm not the Shach Taz M"A etc... (not that u thought I was), I'm a simple Joe Shmoe who wants to know Shulchan Aruch (not Beis Yosef). So, I want to conquer what's after the Sh"a not before (not necessarily the authors intention but that's ok). The Sh"A is what's widely accepted so I'll work my way from there. That being the case, I want to know what's the best route from there... learn what?

Comment: If you want to know Shulchan Aruch, just read it. Then you do whatever you want with that info.

Comment: Well said ty @doubleAA I learn a lot from you ty

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it's hard to see through all the talk. People sometimes use the term Shulchan Aruch as a code for other things, but sometimes it is worth stepping back and remembering it's a sefer with its own worth. Wanting to learn practical Halacha and wanting to learn Shulchan Aruch are two completely different things.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile adopting a 2 pronged approach to this problem, *iyun* and *bekius*. For *iyun* adopt any of the approaches suggested above, for *bekius*, whizz through 10 - 20 *seifim* a day, as long as you have an approximate idea of what the Shulchan Aruch is talking about.

Comment: @DoubleAA Your 1st comment is the best one. In this day and age, most people in my experience never look at the author’s introduction which states clearly how to learn the sefer. As a general rule, anytime someone picks up a new Sefer, they should always look at the author’s intro to understand what the intent of the book is and its structure.

Comment: I think anyone would draw the correct conclusion from all the answers here: Describing the "best approach" to learning isn't best. People have many different methods, and have to work out what works best for them. Try it, and see what you can do and what you find helpful. Don't forget to chazer!

Answer (score 2):

Halachah is constantly evolving, so it's worth noting that the Shulchan Aruch is just a starting point, rather than an end to itself. If you want practical halachah, as the other answer suggests, use the more contemporary digests which include modern teshuvos, etc. Nonetheless, it is always worth knowing how to start learning Halachah from the Tur/Shulchan Aruch onward.

If you want to specifically start with the Shulchan Aruch and not the Tur, the following are my recommendations.

#### B'bekiyus

The most basic way to learn SA will be to start with SA and Ba'er Heitev. The Ba'er Heitev is a digest of commentaries on all of SA, much like the Mishnah Berurah is on Orach Chaim.

#### B'iyun

If you want to go in depth, the best way to learn Shulchan Aruch is from the Gemara: Start with a sugya (maybe an amud or so) and then learn the associated halachos in the SA quoted in the Ein Mishpat on that Gemara. Learn them with the Beiur HaGra to understand why those opinions are followed from the machlokesin in the Gemara, and then learn the commentaries associated with that se'if.

#### A sample order of learning

[image: Shulchan Aruch]

1. Shulchan Aruch
2. Be'er Hagolah (to see where the halachah is from--Gemara, Rambam, etc.)
3. Beiur HaGra (to see how the machlokes plays out)
4. The commentaries to the left and right of the Shulchan Aruch (in Orach Chaim that is the Turei Zahav, aka Taz, and the Magen Avraham). I like to start with the commentary on the inside and then do the one on the outside, but however you do it is up to you.
5. However much of the rest of it you want to do. For example, the Pri Megadim in Orach Chaim is split between the Eishel Avraham (a commentary on the Magen Avraham) and the Mishbetzos Zahav (a commentary on the Turei Zahav).
6. Finish up with the Ba'er Heitev and the Shaarei Teshuvah. The Shaarei Teshuvah is written on the Ba'er Heitev, and its numbering system follows the Ba'er Heitev.

Your own Shulchan Aruch may be set up differently, there are multiple ways the Shulchan Aruch is printed. My preference is the [Shulchan Aruch Habahir](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=11713&strReferer=search&PPGR=0).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many studying for semicha using summary style seforim, some of which will mention more recent poskim. See a selection here http://www.smicha.co.il/sfarim.php?it=4. Other popular options are שיעורי שבט הלוי or פחתי תשוב**ות** (not to be confused with פתחי תשובה).

Comment: Thank you @Solomonlight

Comment: The only way to learn halacha is like any other subject, first making a type of decision tree of what you want to know. A good sefer on this on MB is halacha ulmaaseh available on the otsar.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p24i8aohr4rhvhq/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20-%20%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20108.pdf?dl=0 Here is an example from this sefer